# Laravel unique value validation only when sibling field is same

Tags: php, laravel

Could someone please help to understand how to create store method validation in ***Laravel*** for the table with the current structure.

```
Schema::create('product_areas', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('area_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
});
```

The `area_id` field must be unique only when it has the same `product_id` within the same model.

This should be possible:

```
['id' => 1, 'area_id' => 1, 'product_id' => 1]
['id' => 2, 'area_id'=> 1, 'product_id' => 2]
```

Where this should throw an error:

```
['id' => 1, 'area_id' => 1, 'product_id' => 1]
['id' => 2, 'area_id'=> 1, 'product_id' => 1]
```

I have read the documentation but have not found similar scenario. I have very little idea of how this could be implemented.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a Composite Key (or Multi-Column Index). I would expect that different databases handle this differently, so you should do some research on the topic for your selected database (didn't include a tag in your question, can't assume)

Comment: The problem is that eloquent does not support composite keys

Comment: Natively, no, it doesn't. That being said, defining a Composite Key in your database will cause inserts/updates to fail when a conflict is found, which you can catch and handle in your code. Otherwise, you could do a pre-insert check of some kind, but I'm not sure of a specific approach.

Comment: Sorry guys, what do you mean "eloquent does not support composite keys"? it's possible for migration to describe composite primary key as well as composite unique index. do you mean validation inside Eloquent query before request is executed?

Answer (score 0):

You can conditionally add a validation rule:

```
$v = Validator::make($data, [
    'area_id' => 'required|integer',
    'product_id' => 'required|integer',
]);

$v->sometimes('area_id', 'unique:product_areas', function ($input) {
    $products = \App\Product::where('id', $input->product_id)->count();
    return $products > 0;
});
```

The above logic will only apply the rule for `area_id` when the `product_id` returns at least one entry from the database. Here's the relevant [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#conditionally-adding-rules). You can also add a new validation rule, but I think the above may suffice in your case.

Comment: That does not really work, as I need to validate two fields of product_areas model.  It should have looked something like this in real world `['area_id' => 'required'|unique:product_areas, area_id, where product_id is unique within product_areas

Comment: composite keys seems to be a good match for resolution but it is not supported by eloquent

Comment: The only feasible validation would be something like that grab all product_areas where product_id === $request->only('product_id'), then check if retrieved models contain the $request->only('area_id') and fail if so.

Comment: The logic within the `sometimes` method can be whatever you need it to be. All that matters is that it returns `true` when you need `area_id` to be unique and `false` when you don't. As for making sure `area_id` is always required, I've updated the answer for that.

Comment: If I return true or false nothing change validation still passes

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the solution, but the solution was that good because I would have to make the additional query on each validation. Here is the solution I came up with:

```
$v = Validator::make($request->all(), [
'area_id' => [
  'required', 
  Rule::unique('product_areas')->where(function($query) use($request){
  return $query->where('product_id', $request->get('product_id'))->get()->count() === 0;
})]
], $this->messages);

$v->validate();
```

Then after talking to Ben Johnson @cbj4074 and @UncertaintyP on https://gitter.im  laravel's channel, they advised me to create unique index containing both columns then try insertion and when it caught exception I could respond with a validation erorr.  This was the solution I eventually used.

The composite key which Tim Lewis suggested was also an option but it would not allow identical keys in either columns, so `[product_id=>1, area_id=>2] and [product_id=>2,area_id2]` would throw an exception in case of any of the columns would have identical values.

In order to create unique keys I used `$table->unique(['product_id', 'area_id'])` schema in migration.

Comment: no, composite primary key would not fail on saving `[product_id=>1, area_id=>2]` and `[product_id=>2,area_id2]`; it would fail only on identical set of values

Comment: actually 'composite primary key' and 'unique index containing both columns' are semantically the same